# Setting java classpath only when compiling

Tags: java, ant, classpath

Is it possible to set the class path only when using `javac` but then run the program without specifying the class path at `java`?

For example,

I am using `ant` that does the compiling for me and it sets the class path to `./:lib/swingx-all-1.6.3.jar`. As far as I know, this basically compiles/uses `javac` with that class path.

So is it possible to then run my program with just `java MainApp`, i.e. without having to use a class path variable? Or is it only possible to run my program by using the ant command again?

Comment: You can create an all-in-one jar, or set the classpath in the manifest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bundle your application in a `jar` file. Then include your classpath in `manifest`.

Here are `Ant` manuals for [jar](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/jar.html) and [manifest](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/manifest.html) tasks.

Then, to run your application:

`$ java -jar MainApp.jar`

---

If you can use ant to run your program, look at the [java task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/java.html). Create a new target named "run" or something like that.

Comment: I can't do that. This is for a CS course project and I have to provide the .java files.

Comment: I don't get why you can't do this. If you give your `.java` sources **and** the ant build script, the same jar can be reproduced. Or, if you want, you can put your source files in the jarfile too.

Comment: The requirement for the project is that the program will be compiled using ant or javac MainApp and then run using java MainApp <arguments>.

Comment: Then you're out of luck. Without classpath environment variable, you'll need to set the classpath this way: `$ java -cp path/to/classes MainApp <mainApp args>`.

Comment: You said that you can use ant to run your program? It's very strange... you can't bundle in a jar (which anyone with a jre will run), but can with a dev tool (that not even all developers use).

Comment: So is has to be set when compiling MainApp (javac) **and** when running MainApp (java)?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26191/discussion-between-jean-waghetti-and-imaddin)

Comment: Another thing, `ant` will only be used for compiling the program. `java` is still used for running it, which doesn't make sense to me since the class path I set for ant isn't the same as when my program will be tested with the `java` command.

Comment: You said "Or is it only possible to run my program by using the ant command again?". If it is your constraint not putting any parameter between `java` and your application class name, then I see no other way to set the classpath than env variable.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to set the classpath environment variable; you can always supply a classpath manually with the `-cp` option.

Comment: But the thing is, I only want the class path to be set when running `javac` but not when running `java`.